# Autoencoder doesn't learn to reduce dimesions

Tags: python, autoencoder, accuracy

I coded a neural network from scratch in Python. I tried it with the XOR problem and it learned correctly. So I tried to encode an Autoencoder with 3 inputs (and therefore with also 3 outputs) to reduce a color (r, g, b) in one dimension. I have normalized the data from 0 to 1 so I can use activation functions like sigmoid, relu etc. I have tried many different activation functions and learning rates, but the Autoencoder error(calculated with the mean squared error) is high (the lowest I got is 0.1), although I have trained it for more than 30,000 iterations. Did I miss something? (I think so, but is it possible to reduce a color to a size with good accuracy in the first place?)

Thank you all

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Yes, I was trying to reduce any possible color... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of color are you trying to learn? If it's a random color, then yep, tough luck, you can't reduce the dimensionality of a 3D Euclidian manifold to less than 3D.

To be more precise, this is the case for an infinite manifold, for non-infinite one, you could get a 1D curve that goes through a 3D cube (in philosophy, it would be close to a Kohonen map, despite having just one node instead of a set of discrete nodes), but you would need a very big set of intermediate layers to make it happen.